# How to use a method as a goroutine function

Tags: go, goroutine

I have this code. I expect to output:

```
hello : 1 
world : 2
```

but it outputs:

```
world : 2
world : 2
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Task struct {
    name string
    data int32
}

func (this *Task) PrintData() {
    fmt.Println(this.name, ":", this.data)
}

func main() {
    tasks := []Task{{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}}
    for _, task := range tasks {
        go task.PrintData()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5000)
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `PrintData` is a pointer receiver and `task` is a value, the compiler automatically takes the address of `task` when making the method call. The resulting call is the same as `(&task).PrintData()`.

The variable `task` is set to a different value on each iteration through the loop.  The first goroutine doesn't run until `task` is set to second value.  Run [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/2bQC9V7Wj7) to see that the same address is passed to PrintData on each iteration.

There are a few ways to fix this. The first is to use `*Task` in the slice:

```
tasks := []*Task{{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}}
for _, task := range tasks {
    go task.PrintData()
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/h0NT4QUXNo)

The second is to create a new variable inside the loop:

```
tasks := []Task{{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}}
for _, task := range tasks {
    task := task
    go task.PrintData()
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/EW0WurHIdX)

A third is to take the address of the slice element (using the automatically inserted address operation):

```
tasks := []Task{{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}}
for i := range tasks {
    go tasks[i].PrintData()
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/-KaQeVD9sC)

Yet another option is to change PrintData to a value receiver to prevent the method call from automatically taking the address of `task`:

```
func (this Task) PrintData() {
    fmt.Println(this.name, ":", this.data)
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/kdOKVeO_Ti)

This issue is similar to the [issue discussed in the closures and goroutines FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines). The difference between the issues is the mechanism used to pass a pointer to the goroutine function. The code in the question uses the method's receiver argument. The code in the FAQ uses a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Thanks，the third is better，because I want to modify the member of the structure.

Comment: @Devin, third option is the only way to go if you want to modify the slice.  Please see the updated third option. It's less verbose than the original.

Comment: @Devin First option would also usually work (as long as your intent is to modify the `Task` and not to replace the pointer in the slice with a new pointer), but the third option is still better.

Comment: There has been some discussion around changing this behaviour recently: https://github.com/golang/go/discussions/56010

Answer (score 3):

> [Go Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://golang.org/doc/faq)
>
> [What happens with closures running as goroutines?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines)
>
> Some confusion may arise when using closures with concurrency.
>   Consider the following program:
>
> ```
> func main() {
>     done := make(chan bool)
>
>     values := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
>     for _, v := range values {
>         go func() {
>             fmt.Println(v)
>             done <- true
>         }()
>     }
>
>     // wait for all goroutines to complete before exiting
>     for _ = range values {
>         <-done
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> One might mistakenly expect to see a, b, c as the output. What you'll
>   probably see instead is c, c, c. This is because each iteration of the
>   loop uses the same instance of the variable v, so each closure shares
>   that single variable. When the closure runs, it prints the value of v
>   at the time fmt.Println is executed, but v may have been modified
>   since the goroutine was launched. To help detect this and other
>   problems before they happen, run go vet.
>
> To bind the current value of v to each closure as it is launched, one
>   must modify the inner loop to create a new variable each iteration.
>   One way is to pass the variable as an argument to the closure:
>
> ```
> for _, v := range values {
>     go func(u string) {
>         fmt.Println(u)
>         done <- true
>     }(v)
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the value of v is passed as an argument to the
>   anonymous function. That value is then accessible inside the function
>   as the variable u.
>
> Even easier is just to create a new variable, using a declaration
>   style that may seem odd but works fine in Go:
>
> ```
> for _, v := range values {
>     v := v // create a new 'v'.
>     go func() {
>         fmt.Println(v)
>         done <- true
>     }()
> }
> ```
>
> ---

Just create a new variable for the closure using a declaration style that may seem odd but works fine in Go. Add `task := task`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Task struct {
    name string
    data int32
}

func (this *Task) PrintData() {
    fmt.Println(this.name, ":", this.data)
}

func main() {
    tasks := []Task{{"hello", 1}, {"world", 2}}
    for _, task := range tasks {
        task := task
        go task.PrintData()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5000)
}
```

Output:

```
hello : 1
world : 2
```

Comment: @MuffinTop: You claim is clearly false. Read [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for edit my question,I understand now